# How do I append elements to a matrix using a for loop?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have following data matrix, I want to iterate over this matrix and look at a value in the last column based on a given row and add that row - last element of that row to a new matrix.

```
5.1000    3.3000    1.7000    0.5000    1.0000
6.8000    3.2000    5.9000    2.3000    3.0000
5.0000    2.3000    3.3000    1.0000    2.0000
7.4000    2.8000    6.1000    1.9000    3.0000
6.5000    3.2000    5.1000    2.0000    3.0000
4.8000    3.4000    1.9000    0.2000    1.0000
4.9000    3.0000    1.4000    0.2000    1.0000
5.1000    3.8000    1.5000    0.3000    1.0000
5.1000    3.4000    1.5000    0.2000    1.0000
5.5000    2.6000    4.4000    1.2000    2.0000
```

This is the code that I have

```
 M1 = [];
 M2 = [];
 M3 = [];
    for i=1:length(currentCell)
        if currentCell(1,5) == 1.00
            m3Data = currentCell(1:1,1:4);
            %how can I add m3Data to M1
        end
    end
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to append, a single value, a row, a row composed of copies that single value...

Comment: This part: _"and add that row - last element of that row to a new matrix."_ needs to be clarified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let your original matrix be `M`, then this

```
M1 = M(find(M(:,5)==1),1:4)
```

puts all the rows ending with a `1` into M1, excluding the final column.  Is that what you want ?

You could do it with a for loop if you want, but I don't see any need.

Comment: Sorry about that I got the answer